Path issue? Cordova - No installed build tools found. Please install the Android build tools version
Cordova doesn't find "build tools" for Android platform. But it's installed.
I don't understand what is wrong. I read a lot of posts on this kind of issues but without result.
When I try to build cordova app I have this error:
$ cordova build android
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_HOME=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/Users/ja/Library/Android/sdk (DEPRECATED)
Using Android SDK: /usr/local/Caskroom/android-platform-tools/35.0.1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 989ms
1 actionable task: 1 up-to-date
Subproject Path: CordovaLibSubproject Path: app
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* Where:Script '/Users/ja/Documents/works/stellantis/tablets-app/hello/platforms/android/CordovaLib/cordova.gradle' line: 73
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> No installed build tools found. Please install the Android build tools version 34.0.0.

2 questions :

Why ANDROID_HOME is undefined ?

Why cordova use /usr/local/Caskroom/android-platform-tools/35.0.1 and not /Users/ja/Library/Android/sdk ?


I'm on Mac Sonoma 14.5
$ cordova -v   => 12.0.0 (cordova-lib@12.0.1)
I have a fresh install of Android Studio. In the "Tools" menu:

There is only SDK version 14 installed (hiding or not obsolete packages) into Android Studio.
The path: /Users/ja/Library/Android/sdk
I use ZSH ( $ echo $SHELL  =>  /bin/zsh )
Files ~/.bash_profile and ~/.zshrc  contain :
export ANDROID_HOME=~/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools

As explained on https://developer.android.com/tools/variables
I try $ source ~/.bash_profile  and $ source ~/.zshrc
Build Tools is present: /Users/ja/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/34.0.0
No suggestion during StackOverflow review works.
What's wrong ?
Tell me if I forgot something to show.
Thank You.

What just worked in my case, put:
export ANDROID_HOME=~/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
In the files ~/.bash_profile and ~/.zshrc
$ source ~/.bash_profile
$ source ~/.zshrc
Exit the terminal completely and then relaunch it. The cordova command now works fine.

I've just had the same problem as OP on Windows 11, because Android Studio apparently doesn't automatically set the environment variables for us. I've navigated to my %ANDROID_HOME% to check and there's a platform-tools/ but no tools/. Can you please elaborate (e.g. what should I find in it) so I can find it on my own?

Update your platforms\android\cdv-gradle-config.json
"SDK_VERSION":35 and "MIN_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION":"35.0.0"


I was facing the same issue.
After hours of trying to restart Android Studio, removing the platform, invalidating caches, etc., what actually worked was to remove the build tools from the Android Studio SDK manager and install them again.
So I invalidated the cache just to be sure, restarted Android Studio again and everything worked as expected.
